# Automatically scroll UITableView to show row **below** the row being edited

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I have `UITableView` in a ViewController (not a `UITableViewController`) with `UITextFields` in each row. I would like the TableView to automatically scroll so that the row **below** the row being edited is always displayed. This allows the user to tap the next row to edit it. The built in iOS Reminders app has this behaviour.

I have followed [Apple's advice on managing the keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW3) but that only scrolls to show the row you are editing just above the keyboard, **not the row below it**.

I have tried adjusting the frame in `scrollRectToVisible:` but it makes no difference. In fact commenting out that line of code seems to have no effect at all.

It seems that the `UITableView` will always try to scroll to show the `UITextfield` being edited just above the keyboard, and I can't find a way of adjusting or overriding this behaviour so that it shows the row below it also.

**Update:**

I've found that the automatic scrolling behaviour can be prevented by overriding the private `scrollTextFieldToVisible` method of `UITextField`.
However, the automatic scrolling code provided by Apple in the linked documentation still does not work.

Comment: You might want to read the related documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW44

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting setContentOffset property instead of scrollRectToVisible. like

```
[self->_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, textFieldRect.origin.y)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below link, it will make your work very easy. 
Just add the files and make the tableview class name as "TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView"

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding